# The View is Not Showing Data in an ASP.NET MVC App With MySQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mysql-connector

I am having a hard time getting data from the MySQL database within my ASP.NET MVC web app. At first I couldn't even connect to it, but I've figured that out.

Here is the code of the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Show a list of e-books available for purchase.
        eBookDbContext eBooksContext = new ExpLang.Models.eBookDbContext();
        return View(eBooksContext.eBooks.ToList());
    }
```

Here is the code of the context:

```
    public class eBookDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<eBook> eBooks { get; set; }
    }
```

I think this DbContext is the problem. I followed the Microsoft tutorial and it didn't instruct me to place any code in the get;set.

Here is the code for the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ExpLang.Models.eBook>
```

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Language)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Try debugging your code.

Comment: Separate the database call into a new variable so you can debug and see if it brings back any data. Also while debugging look at the properties of the context and see if you are connecting to the database you think you are connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Entry>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.string1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.decimal1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date1)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EntriesController : Controller
    {
        private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

        // GET: Entries
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Entries.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string string1 { get; set; }
        public decimal decimal1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime date1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Connection String:

```
<add name="DatabaseContext"connectionString="Datasource=server;Database=schemaName;uid=username;pwd=password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Comment: So I made sure the connection string name is set to eBookDbContext. Then I set a break point on that line of code. When expanding the properties I saw this, "The function evaluation requires all threads to run."

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the next line (the closing bracket) and continue to that one, then check the value of the list being returned.

Comment: Okay, so the error still shows, but this is new: Sql = "SELECT\r\n`Extent1`.`ID`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Title`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Description`, \r\n`Extent1`.`ReleaseDate`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Language`, \r\n`Extent1`.`Price`\r\nFROM `eBooks` AS `Extent1`" 

I tried to show the apostrophe but it won't let me here.

Comment: I've edited my answer with code from an application I quickly set up. All is tested and working, see if using this will solve the problem you're having.